# Getting list of changes or commits associated with build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there any way to get a list of changes or commits associated with build? And is there any way to get these changes using predefined variables like `Build.Repository` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no [pre-defined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for list of changes (commits) but there is a [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-build-changes?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) for that:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/changes?api-version=6.1-preview.2
```